# Drupal direct link add node in node

Tags: drupal, reference, hyperlink, edit

I've got a drupal website, with Page and Paragraphs. I need a solution to add a Paragraph directly in a Page with a link. My paragraphs are linked to the page by `node reference` module.

Something like: `mywebsite.com/node/add/paragraph?nid-page=21`

With this link i will be able to add a new paragraph, and the corresponding page will automatically be updated with this new paragraph.

I hope i was clear enough.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

I would register a new callback (similar to the above) which retrieves the paragraph node form, adds a new submit callback too the form which does :

1. Add node reference
2. Add form redirect to the page node page.

Then render this form.

Or, you can use URL params like you have above and do a form alter on the paragraph node form when that URL param is present. The form alter would do the same as the above.

If you need a code example let me know and I can whip something up in a bit.